# Can I change my PC's class without telling the DM?

Tags: dnd-5e

I was wondering if I can change my PC class without the DM saying I can or without their knowledge. My character is a level 5 Rogue and I don't like the class anymore.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: Why don't you want your DM to know?

Answer (score 17):

No, you can't.  The game rules allow a way for you to gain new levels in other classes, but they don't allow any way for you to change your existing levels.

Even if the game rules did allow a way for you to change your existing levels, there's really no way to do anything in D&D without informing the DM.

The usual solution for your problem is you tell the DM: "I'm retiring my character and I'd like to bring in a new one at the same level."  Then you tell a brief story about what your old character does after leaving the party, and you build a new character from scratch.

If your relationship with your DM is so bad that you don't want them to know what you're doing with your character, you might consider leaving your game and joining a new one with a different DM.  D&D gives a great deal of power to the DM of the game, and the balance for this power is that players will leave the game if they're not having fun.  Don't get into a mindset where you "have to stay in the game".

Answer (score 6):

### No.

There are no rules in the system for replacing existing levels in one class with those in another class. The closest you can get is multiclassing (PHB 163):

> As you advance in levels, you might primarily remain a member of your original class with just a few levels in another class, or you might change course entirely, never looking back at the class you left behind.

### You can't hide anything from the DM

There are significant social and gameplay issues with trying to hide your class from the DM. Even setting those aside, there's no way you can actually do that--if they're paying any attention at all, your DM is going to notice that your "rogue" is suddenly raging or casting warlock spells.